# How to add commas inbetween items using vi?

Tags: vim

I would like to add commas inbetween the item descriptor and the percentage value in the following data set:

```
Item    Percent
Beer    15%
Bottled Water   5%
Chocolate Bar   15%
Chocolate Dipped Cone   15%
Gummy Bears 15%
Hamburger   5%
Hot Dog 5%
Ice Cream Sandwich  15%
Licorice Rope   15%
Nachos  5%
Pizza   5%
Popcorn 5%
Popsicle    15%
Soda    15%
```

I tried something like `s/ /, /`, but then I get a comma between `Hot Dog`, which is not what I want. The comma should be only after the text descriptor.

I also thought I could try to recognize the first digit and add the comma just in front of it, but I cant seem to figure out how digits are recognized. When I use `\d` for that, the digit is *replaced* and not remembered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple `:normal` solution:

```
:%norm! f%F ciw,
```

Breakdown:

```
f%             move the cursor on the %
F<space>       move the cursor on the first space to the left
ciw,<space>    replace the whitespace under the cursor with a comma followed by a space
```

See `:help :normal`.

Answer (score 3):

take the one you think correct, (you didn't give an output example)

### 1

```
%s/\s\d/,&/
```

will give

```
Hot Dog   ,5%
```

### 2

```
%s/\s*\d/,&/
```

will give

```
Hot Dog,   5%
```

### 3

```
%s/\s*\ze\d/, /
```

will give

```
Hot Dog, 5%
```

the last one replaces spaces into one

Answer (score 3):

Capture the digit with `\(...\)` and replicate it in the output with `\1`.

```
:%s/ \([0-9]\)/ ,\1/
```

But since you have multiple spaces, you probably want the comma before all of them. So add them to the capture group:

```
:%s/\( *[0-9]\)/,\1/
```

Even better, you can protect against digits in the item descriptor (e.g. "7 layer burrito") by matching the percent sign too. Capture all the digits and the percent sign and replicate them:

```
:%s/\( *[0-9][0-9]*%\)/,\1/
```

Basic Regular Expressions as used in traditional `vi` don't have `\d` so I have a habit of using `[0-9]` instead. With the less portable vim regular expressions you could shorten the above to:

```
:%s/\( *\d\+%\)/,\1/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:%s/\ze\s\+\d\+%/,/
```

I tend to prefer `\zs` and `\ze` over groups -> `:h /\ze`